# How to save/load to disk class with non serializable properties?

Tags: c#, class, uwp, save, serializable

I have a class that must be saved to disk and then loaded everytime the app is initialized. I don't care if the file created is a Json, XML or binary. This is the class:

```
    public class PhotoSpot_v01
    {
        public int      ID { get; set; }
        public string   Title { get; set; }
        public string   Description { get; set; }
        public int      Rating { get; set; }
        public bool     Reminder { get; set; }
        public bool     Toast { get; set; }

        private double   Latitude { get; set; }
        private double   Longitude { get; set; }
        private double   Altitude { get; set; }

        public GoogleMapsAPI.TimeZone TimeZone { get; set; }

        public globalVars.Tags MainTag { get; set; }

        public version Version { get; set; }

        public Milestone_v01    Milestone { get; set; }
        public List<Image_v01>  Images { get; set; }
        public List<URL_v01>    URLs { get; set; }
        public List<globalVars.Tag>    Tags { get; set; }
        public List<Date_v01>   Dates { get; set; }}
```

And here, classes and enums, ... used in the main class:

```
    public class Milestone_v01
    {
        public bool     freeMilestone { get; set; }
        public string   Title { get; set; }
        public double   Latitude { get; set; }
        public double   Longitude { get; set; }
        public double   Altitude { get; set; }
        public globalVars.Astro Astro { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Astro
    {
        Sun, Moon, Night, Any
    }


    public class Image_v01
    {
        public string imageURI { get; set; }
        public bool   isDownloaded { get; set; }
    }

    public class URL_v01
    {
        public string sURL { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag_v01
    {
        public globalVars.Tags TagName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Date_v01
    {
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I manage to save enum values and specially DateTime and Geopoint values?

Comment: `enum` values are commonly serialized as their `int` values.

Comment: what is `Geopoint` here? it doesn't appear in the code sample - is that a specific API?

Comment: also: which types are you considering "non serializable" in the above? most if it looks pretty reasonable, although we can't see everything (no idea what `Tags`/`Tag`/`TimeZone` are, for example)

Comment: @MarcGravell Geopoint its a class to work with geospatial position on earth's surface. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geopoint
Tags/Tag are enums and TimeZone it's class with only double and string values in it, so nothing problematic, that's why I haven't inserted in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not actually seeing anything "non serializable" in your model (it looks like any of the major ones would work just fine with that - especially `XmlSerializer`, Json.NET and protobuf-net, which are my usual defaults); no serializer of note should choke on enums or `DateTime`. But: if there really *is* a problematic type somewhere, there are two ways of doing this:

1. most serialization tools/libraries support some kind of "custom serializer" API for when something just doesn't work out of the box; this usually requires you to learn *way* too much about the underlying serialization architecture (example: `IXmlSerializable.ReadXml` - which is just a nightmare to get 100% right for all scenarios); I *do not* usually recommend trying to do this!
2. much simpler: *stop trying to serialize things that aren't naturally serializable*. This problem usually occurs when people insist that they want to serialize their *primary model*, but... that's just going about things the wrong way around: you end up fighting the serializer. Much simpler and more maintainable is to construct a separate model that looks *similar* to your primary model, but which is purely intended to fit the nuances of a particular serializer (if you support multiple serialization formats or different serialization versions, you might even need multiple models in some cases). So: create something *like* your model, but which only makes use of inherently serializable types - and then write a few lines of (usually very simple) code that maps *between* the two models.

In some cases of 2, the serialization tool might even support a "surrogate" concept such that you only need to add this model for *some* types, when they become awkward - but can use the primary model for most other things. For example, protobuf-net allows you to do this as long as there is a conversion operation (implicit or explicit) in both directions between two types - so you could have a `Foo` type, and a `FooSerialization` type which looks a lot like `Foo`, and has conversion operators to/from `Foo`, but which is "simpler" (for want of a better word) - making use of obvious simple types (for example, perhaps using `byte[]` instead of `Image`/`Bitmap` for images).

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I was trying the second approach to get what I wanted: Geopoint convert to something serializable ( double longitude, double latitude, double altitude) and add a method to get from the class converted back to Geopoint class. 
So, this way I can discard Geopoint to be something problematic, and so do I with the enums. This lets me with DateTime struct.

Comment: @ImanolZubiaurre in that scenario, `Geopoint` sounds like something that protobuf-net's "surrogate" API would work well for; I'll put together a more complete example...

Comment: @ImanolZubiaurre note... you don't actually *use* `Geopoint` in your code... so...

Comment: @ImanolZubiaurre a bit like this: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/6b2ca16de970051d28584ef6cc389491

Comment: If I have understood correctly, DateTime is serializable without any further problems.
 If this is correct and they way I have manage Geopoint converting to a similar 3 double values (latitude, longitude and altitude) that can be serializable. My problem should be solved.

Comment: @ImanolZubiaurre just about every serializer I know of can handle `DateTime`; `Geopoint` could be the trickier one, hence my example shows a way of using a library-specific feature (surrogate types) to shim over that without needing to create an *entire* separate model. Disclosure: I'm the author/maintainer of protobuf-net, so I'm much better at giving examples of that library than with the others - similar features may be available in json.net etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use newtonsoft.json.

You can write json converter for DateTime and GeoPoint values to keep them in the form you want and then translate them back when you are deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to Marc Gravell in the conversation above that I cannot post formatted code...

So, if I make this change to DateTime in Date_v01 class that it can be seen in the code given int the question (and in extension to Geopoint too):

```
    public class Date_v01
    {

        public double DateStart;
        public double DateEnd;

        public DateTime DateTimeStart()
        {
            return CoreTime.JD2DateTime(DateStart);
        }

        public DateTime DateTimeEnd()
        {
            return CoreTime.JD2DateTime(DateEnd);
        }

        //public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
        //public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    }
```

the serialization problem should be solved, right?